# Finding a min of vector that index is a member of another vector

Tags: matlab, find, member

I have a vector matrix of a range of values, e.g:

```
x = [9 8 6 7 4 5 1 2];
```

I then have another vector that contains the indices of x values that match a particular criteria, e.g:

```
y = [7 8]; % (that is, elements 7 and 8 of x meet criteria)
```

I now need to find the minimum x, which has its index a member of y.

I have tried the following:

```
find(x == min(x) & ismember(find(x == min(x)), f) == 1)
```

But it doesn't work, it seems to just return a binary answer and even then, still doesn't work. The idea was to find an index that is minimum and is a member using find (where I take the index of the min x for the `ismember`).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
value = min(x(y));
value =  1
```

`x(y)` gives you the elements of `x` that are indexed by `y`. `min` is used to find only the smallest one.

Comment: Perfect, I should have taken a step back to think of it more simply!